# Django REST: How to POST and PUT Data in Nested ModelSerializer

Tags: python, json, django, post, put

I am a novice at Django and already GET data .
Part of some json as follows:

```
{
    "pk": 4,
    "account": "user4",
    "password": "5340",
    "UserDatas": {
        "memberAccount_id": 4,
        "username": "Dylan",
        "gender": true,
        "score": 100,
        "photo": "photos/2016/05/16/avatar.png",
        "TaskDatas": [
            {
                "userData_id": 4,
                "task_name": "make a phone call",
                "task_is_group": false,
                "task_time": "2015/05/18",
                "task_score": 2,
                "task_member_list": "",
                "task_bulletin": "phone number is 1234-5678"
            }
        ],
        "FriendsDatas": [],
        "ChatroomDatas": []
    }
},
```

This is my models.py

```
class MemberAccount(models.Model):
    account = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return  "%s : %s" % (self.account, self.password)

class UserData(models.Model):
    memberAccount_id = models.OneToOneField(
        MemberAccount,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='UserDatas',
        blank=True
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
    gender = models.BooleanField()
    score = models.IntegerField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to ="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", null=True ,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('memberAccount_id', 'username')
        order_with_respect_to = 'memberAccount_id'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s : %s" % (self.memberAccount_id, self.username)

class TaskData(models.Model):
    userData_id = models.ForeignKey(UserData, related_name='TaskDatas', null=True)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    task_is_group = models.BooleanField()
    task_time= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    task_score = models.IntegerField()
    task_member_list = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True ,blank=True)
    task_bulletin = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('userData_id', 'task_name')
        order_with_respect_to = 'userData_id'

    def __str__(self):
        return  "%s : %s" % (self.userData_id, self.task_name)

class ChatroomData(models.Model):
    userdata_cid = models.ForeignKey(UserData, related_name='ChatroomDatas', null=True, blank=True)
    chatroom_member = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    chatroom_contents = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
    # 在Python3中使用 def __str__(self)
    return "%s : %s" % (self.userdata_cid, self.chatroom_member)


class FriendsData(models.Model):
    usersData_id = models.ForeignKey(UserData, related_name='FriendsDatas', null=True)
    friend_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    friend_account = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('usersData_id', 'friend_name')
        order_with_respect_to = 'usersData_id'

    def __str__(self):
    # 在Python3中使用 def __str__(self)
        return  "%s : %s" % (self.usersData_id, self.friend_name)

class SubtaskData(models.Model):
    taskData_id = models.ForeignKey(TaskData, related_name='SubtaskDatas', null=True)
    subtask_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtask_deadline = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subtask_completion= models.IntegerField()
    subtask_importance = models.IntegerField()
    subtask_item = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('taskData_id', 'subtask_name')
        order_with_respect_to = 'taskData_id'

    def  __str__(self):
    # 在Python3中使用 def __str__(self)
        return  "%s : %s" % (self.taskData_id, self.subtask_name)
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def jobterm_list(request, format=None):

    if request.method=="GET":
        MemberAccounts =list(MemberAccount.objects.all()) 
        serializer = MemberAccountSerializer(MemberAccounts,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    elif request.method == 'POST':
        #print (request.body)
        serializer = MemberAccountSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE']) #
def jobterm_detial(request,pk, format=None):
    try:
        member_Account = MemberAccount.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except MemberAccount.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = MemberAccountSerializer(member_Account)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == "PUT":
        serializer = MemberAccountSerializer(member_Account,data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == "DELETE":
        member_Account.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

serializer.py

```
class ChatroomDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChatroomData
        fields = ("userdata_cid", "chatroom_member", "chatroom_contents")

class TaskDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskData
        fields = ("userData_id", "task_name", "task_is_group",
              "task_time", "task_score", "task_member_list",
              "task_bulletin")

class FriendsDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FriendsData
        fields = ("usersData_id","friend_name","friend_account")

class UserDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    TaskDatas = TaskDataSerializer( many = True )
    FriendsDatas = FriendsDataSerializer( many = True )
    ChatroomDatas = ChatroomDataSerializer( many = True )
    class Meta:
        model = UserData
        fields = ("memberAccount_id","username","gender","score",
              "photo","TaskDatas","FriendsDatas","ChatroomDatas")

class MemberAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    UserDatas = UserDataSerializer( required = False )
    class Meta:
        model = MemberAccount
        fields = ("pk","account","password","UserDatas")

class SubtaskDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubtaskData
        fields = ("taskData_id","subtask_name","subtask_deadline","subtask_completion",
              "subtask_importance","subtask_item")
```

I try to override create() and update() method to POST json in serializer.py, but it's too many layer to link. I have no idea about this.

Below is my create method, but it only can POST MemberAccount and UserData.

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    memberaccount = MemberAccount.objects.create(account = validated_data['account'], 
                                                password = validated_data['password'] )

    User_Datas = validated_data.pop('UserDatas')

    for item in User_Datas:
        userdata = UserData.objects.create(username = User_Datas.get('username'),
                              gender = User_Datas.get('gender'),
                               score = User_Datas.get('score'),
                               photo = User_Datas.get('photo'))

        userdata.save()
    return memberaccount
```

The POST json message:

```
{"account":"try3","password":"8493","UserDatas":{"memberAccount_id":0,"username":"Amy","gender":false,"score":100,"photo":null,"TaskDatas":[],"FriendsDatas":[],"ChatroomDatas": []}}
```

Comment: I don't get it. What's the question?

Comment: I want to post all the data of the user include: MemberAccount, UserData, TaskData, FriendsData,SubtaskData,ChatroomData, but now I only can post MemberAccount, UserData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save related models accordingly like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    memberaccount = MemberAccount.objects.create(account = validated_data['account'],
                                            password = validated_data['password'] )
    memberaccount.save()
    User_Datas = validated_data.pop('UserDatas')

    userdata = UserData.objects.create(username = User_Datas.get('username'),
        gender = User_Datas.get('gender'),
        score = User_Datas.get('score'),
        photo = User_Datas.get('photo'),)
    userdata.memberAccount_id = memberaccount

    userdata.save()

    Task_Datas = User_Datas.get('TaskDatas')
    for task in Task_Datas:
        taskdata = TaskData(
            task_name = task.get('task_name'), 
            task_is_group = task.get('task_is_group'), 
            task_time = task.get('task_time'), 
            task_score = task.get('task_score'), 
            task_member_list = task.get('task_member_list'), 
            task_bulletin = task.get('task_bulletin'), 
        )
        taskdata.userData_id = userdata
        taskdata.save()

    return memberaccount
```

Comment: May I ask another question? I try the above code and I don't know how to assign the id number by json, such as: memberAccount_id, userData_id etc.? When I post the non-existent id number, the error message will show the id already exists but it does not exist in fact.

Comment: In django, it should be a instance of your model(e.g. MemberAccount, UserData). If it's a non-existent id, this should be a new instance. You shouldn't assign any id on your post data.

Comment: I don't know if this model design is necessary for your application. Otherwise, you should merge MemberAccount and UserData model. The post data will become two level only. It will be easier for you to deal with post data.

Comment: But when I do not to assign it, it will be wrong, too. The message will show "detail":"JSON parse error. What does ["Invalid pk \"21\" - object does not exist." mean? While trying to assign a new id number, it sometime will show that message or show non-existent id (21 is new id number). It made me confused.

Comment: While you are creating a new MemberAccount, you don't need to assign pk in post data. A new pk will be generated when new instance is created. The error message you posted means that it can't find a instance with pk(or id) 21.

Comment: Hi, I try your code, but it didn't work. The error  message showed AttributeError :'list' object has no attribute 'get'.  I think  User_Datas is a list, so I can't do this " username = User_Datas.get('username')".

Comment: The code above is based on your original post data. If the post data of "UserDatas" section changed from dict to list, you should also change create() function to deal with list structure.

Comment: Thanks. I finished my create() method. Could give me any tips for update() method? I don't know how to deal with the second and third layer.

Comment: If it is a update() method, you should use pk in post data to get an exist object. Replace UserData.objects.create(username = User_Datas.get('username') to UserData.objects.filter(pk = User_Datas.get('username') for first level. Use TaskData.objects.filter(pk=task_pk) to get the second level object and modify it with your post data.

Answer (score 0):

These are the options I see:

- You can create a set of chained POST calls, if you don't mind atomicity (I wouldn't recommend this option)
- Split your front-end UI/UX so you can isolate data and make it easy to handle. For instance, different panels for each of them
- Save on edit (on front-end), so you can as previous one, sync small pieces of data
- Handle the data on the views (backend). You will need to deal with atomicity as well but you can lean on validators. In this case you need to create serializer instances for each of them
- Create a nested serializer with a list of serializers as properties but as you said, you might need to deal with more than one layer

Comment: I'm very appreciate for your answer, but it still confused me. Could you give me some specific examples?

Comment: I would like to try the last one because I think it's much easier for me to realize.

Comment: Ok. Have you checked this example already? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships